# WhatsApp is not opening in android version 12 and higher in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, whatsapp

I am working on a project in Flutter and I want to open whatsApp from the app. All things working good, whatsApp is opening on every android device but not opening on android version 12

Comment: "they ask for some permission" well, it would be helpful to know *what* permission. And then let the user grant it if you need it.

Comment: No they dont ask for permission I read it in the chatGpt

Comment: "Flutter Code by example"? What does that mean?

Comment: I mean that if someone knows the answer then provide an example of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably caused by the [change in package visibility starting with Android 11](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9).

You need specify that your app needs to interact with other apps in your manifest file. Add Whatsapp's package name explicitly like this:

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring

Comment: Thankyou for your reply can you please elaborate more. I am new flutter developer what should i write in com.example.store. I want to access for whatsapp.

Comment: I updated my example. Afaik the package name for WhatsApp on android has com.whatsapp

Answer (score 0):

As I noticed you want to launch WhatsApp from your App using Flutter. You can use the package mentioned below.
https://pub.dev/packages/whatsapp_unilink

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34583528)